# Looped call on rows in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, call

I'm trying to run a call on my top row, then delete that row and move cells below up and run it on the new top row again. Repeat excercise till there are no more rows left. And yes I know this is probably a slow way of doing it, but my call takes about 10 secs for each row, so it's a nice way of keeping track of the progression (i.e how many rows are left).

This is what I've got so far, but its not understanding my request to delete range A2:C2 and move cells below up if there is a value in Range A3.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Sub loop_through_rows()

Dim rngQuantityCells As Range

Set rngQuantityCells = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))

For i = 1 To rngQuantityCells
Call RunSplit

If Range("A3").Value > 0
then
Range("A2:C2”).Delete Shift:=xlUp

End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: How/When are you setting the variable rngSinglecell?

Comment: If you can give a screenshot with explanation, it would help you get a better answer.

Comment: (Do you not get an error? Your `then` should be on the same line as `If`, AFAIK).

Comment: I get a "compile error: syntax error" around my Range("A2:C2”).Delete Shift:=xlUp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub loop_through_rows()
Dim rngQuantityCells As Range
Set rngQuantityCells = Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlDown))

For i = 1 To rngQuantityCells
    Call RunSplit
    If Range("A3").Value > 0 Then
        Range("A2:C2").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Note you needed the `Then` on the same line. Also, you have two "styles"(?) of quotes in your original post on the `Range("A2:C2")`.

Comment: Thanks alot, what silly mistakes! Got it working after some small twerks. Much appreciated!